# Error whilsted using QGIS 3.4.4 r.series batch processing

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, batch, qgis-3

I'm having some trouble using the Batch Processing to perform r.series, Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm using QGIS 3.4.4.

Output Log:

> Processing algorithm 1/1… Algorithm r.series starting… Input
>   parameters: {'-n': False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META': 'XML',
>   'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT': 'GTiff', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':
>   10.0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None, 'input': 'D:\LocalDataStore\Pre-Processing\DecloudedRasters\18NVM\Band_02\Declouded_RT_T18NVM_20151221T153112_B02.tif;D:\LocalDataStore\Pre-Processing\DecloudedRasters\18NVM\Band_02\Declouded_RT_T18NVM_20151224T153612_B02.tif',
>   'method': [2], 'output': , 'quantile': 'float',
>   'range': '-1,1e+08', 'weights': '1'}
>
> g.region n=0.0 s=0.0 e=0.0 w=0.0 res=10.0 r.series method="median"
>   quantile="float" weights="1" range="-1,1e+08"
>   output=outputf220a810b6eb44f884953602e7378fcf --overwrite g.region
>   raster=outputf220a810b6eb44f884953602e7378fcf r.out.gdal -t -m
>   input="outputf220a810b6eb44f884953602e7378fcf" output="D:\TEST_3.tif"
>   format="GTiff" createopt="GTiff" metaopt="XML" --overwrite Cleaning up
>   temporary files... access: No such file or directory Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 413, in processAlgorithm Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands,
>   feedback, self.outputCommands) File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 386, in executeGrass feedback.reportError(line.strip())
>   TypeError: reportError(self, error: str, fatalError: bool): not enough
>   arguments
>
> Batch execution completed in 1.62 seconds

Comment: `g.region n=0.0 s=0.0 e=0.0 w=0.0 res=10.0` is the problem. You are calculating the median for two raster and the algorithm don't know from wich define the region. `quantile="float"` is another strange log, a float between 0 and 1 is expected.

Comment: But the problem is with the python algorithm in batch mode: with one layer doesn't work in batch mode, with many layers works fine in simple mode. I'm finding worse problems in batch mode. Some algorithms of QGIS 3.4.4 cannot even start the batch mode window due to python errors (i.e, IDW and TIN interpolations). In r.series tool the batch process can not be saved and reopened, which generates an error. I don't know if it's the same for Linux users.